# Streaming specific setup for audio streaming

Tags: amazon-ec2, streaming, audio-streaming, wowza

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

So I have an amazon ec2 instance (m3.medium which I have suddenly realized yields me 4gb of storage) running with wowza server installed for live streaming audio and audio/video on demand. Everything is running fine...things seem to be going swimmingly as we have been live for a week now.

Everyday we have close to 80 people listen in on the live stream and usually that falls to 20-10 concurrent users listening to archived streams at any given time. We hope to increase this number in time.

We have the live/record app and the vod app that we use for streaming and vod/aod respectively. After the streaming show is done it saves the file to the content folder as you know.

So I was cruising the file system checking out the content folder and thinking that eventually this folder is going to fill up and was curious how people navigate this part of streaming- the storage part. It definitely feels like the easiest route as far as storage goes, though I know of the perils involved in keeping all of these files on the instance.

For storing these sorts of files that need to remain available in perpetuity, which tend to add up space-wise, what is the manner in which people commonly do this?

I tried briefly to mount an s3 and it just didn't work for me.  I'm sure that can be fixed but I kept reading that its not recommended to write or stream from s3.

Thanks..any info and leads is a big help. Total newbie here and surprised I even made it this far.

I'll probably need to start a new instance and transfer everything over to a new instance unless there is a way for me to attach more storage to the instance.

Thanks.

Comment: What protocol are you using for on-demand?  If you're just using HTTP, I'd definitely ship that stuff off to S3 and let S3 serve it.  If you have a lot of traffic, use CloudFront in front of S3.

Comment: Hi brad.  Thanks. We are actually using rtmp and http.  Ok. So maybe I dig into s3 again.  Had some trouble writing directly to the s3 from Wowza but I'll give it a go again. Thanks.

Comment: FUSE for S3 is a real pain.  You won't be able to write to S3 directly from Wowza, but you could script something to write there, and script something to fetch the data.  Really though you're probably better off with EBS since you're using RTMP and must serve with Wowza.

Comment: Appreciate it brad. Yeah had some wild times with FUSE.   Thanks for the tip.  I had a hard time understanding the difference between those two but found some literature on it. IA this how most people serve up video and audio on demand?  Or do they just keep it there on the instance?  I was debating switching to an instance with much more space but I feel like best practices says no

Comment: For all the radio sites I work on, I don't even bother with RTMP.  There is little benefit over HTTP for most use cases.  Sticking with HTTP simplifies everything.  If you don't need the extra functionality provided by RTMP, I recommend using HTTP.  Also, I just remembered that you can use CloudFront to serve RTMP from your S3 bucket.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/StreamingDistributionS3Origin.html  Just write a script where Wowza puts files in a temp directory that your scripts then sends to S3.

Comment: Brad, have you ever worked with Wowza before?  It seams there are a lot of extras with wowza that allow this sort of fucntionality.  I've tried it before, written a couple modules that never seemed to work.  In any case, just curious.

Comment: Admittedly, I have not used Wowza any time recently.  I set it up years ago, but that was some versions ago.  I haven't had the need for it.  For live streaming, I developed my own streaming server which provides some better compatibility on mobile devices than a typical Icecast or SHOUTcast configuration.  For on-demand, I've found normal HTTP servers to be sufficient.  But, that's not to say there aren't use cases where Wowza is a very appropriate solution.  I just personally haven't needed it.

Comment: Hi chaz, I have an Amazon ec2 instance and a personal domain. I would like to stream a temporary radio station for a few weeks. Can you please share the references that helped you setup audio streaming..I have been trying for last 2 weeks

Comment: @ztit sure. What sort of system are you setting up?  I think for something smaller you don't need to go the wowza amazon route as it was terribly complicated.  However, wowza does have a boat load of documentation in which i learned of some complete software packages that handle some of the streaming headaches for you.  I'd check there first.  I will say I will never venture down this road again. Ha.  Sorry for the late response.  Hadn't realized you commented.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is going to be your best option. But s3 is not a block storage device like an EBS volume. So you can really open a file on it and write to like a stream.

Instead, you need break your files apart (on some breakpoint that works for you) and upload the file to s3 after its been completed. With that you can have users directly download from S3 and remove load from your current instance.

Comment: So what you are saying is to remove them from the running instance after recording/streaming has finished, then reupload to s3 and serve from there?  I am a little unclear by the "break your files apart".   Is this so that they are served in bits so that streaming is faster?

Comment: How continuous are your streams? If its something you have running constantly you need to pick breakpoints to stop and generate a new file. If the stream only lasts for a set period of time, you can upload after the stream is finished.